# How can I change the bulb in this three-clawed, ceiling-mounted dome light fixture?

Tags: lighting, ceiling, light-fixture, bulb

I am having trouble retrieving the light bulb in this fixture:

[image: Angle 1]
[image: Angle 2]
[image: Angle 3]

I tried bending the claws to release the dome, but that did not work. I tried twisting the whole fixture many times in either direction, but it did not seem to help to remove the fixture. I tried pulling and wiggling the fixture out of the hole in the ceiling, and it came down a little bit, but it did not come out completely, and I am afraid of breaking something if I pull harder.

What should I do to replace the lightbulb here?

Comment: I have this exact light fixture with the same problem. This light has reduced me to tears and reduced my self esteem ... until now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually at least one of the "claws" is spring-loaded, and can be pulled straight out to release the glass.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was exactly the case here. Thanks a lot! 

Comment: Same problem, thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction :)